# Find $x$ and $y$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\frac{\tan 8°}{1-3\tan^{2}8°}+\frac{3\tan 24°}{1-3\tan^{2}24°}+\frac{9\tan 72°}{1-3\tan^{2}72°}+\frac{27\tan 216°}{1-3\tan^{2}216°}=x\tan 108°+y\tan 8°$, find x and y. I am unable to simplify the first and third terms. I am getting power 4 expressions. Thanks.

Comment: What did you do to get four degree terms?

Comment: Combined the first and third terms

Comment: Try expanding $$\tan 3x = \frac{\tan x}{1 - 3\tan^2 x}(3 - \tan^2 x)$$

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But it doesn't help much.

Comment: Isn't this a line? So there are infinitely many solutions $(x,y)$.

Comment: @uranix could you please tell me what to do after writing all the terms in the form of tan3x

Comment: @You-know-me Sorry, I don't know. I just saw similar expression and thought that was a right track

Comment: @ET93 I suppose that The problem asks about simple (rational or so) expressions for $x$, $y$. I.e. simplify to the givenform and find $x, y$.

Comment: Yeah, I know.. But the question is simplification..

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\tan(3\cdot8^\circ)=\dfrac{3\tan 8^\circ-\tan^38^\circ}{1-3\tan^28^\circ}$$

Now, $$\frac{\tan 8^\circ}{1-3\tan^28^\circ}-y\tan8^\circ=\dfrac{(1-y)\tan 8^\circ-(-3y)\tan^38^\circ}{1-3\tan^28^\circ}$$ which will be a multiple of $\tan(3\cdot8^\circ)$ if
 $$\dfrac{1-y}{-3y}=\dfrac31\iff y=-\dfrac18$$

$$\implies\frac{\tan A}{1-3\tan^2A}-\left(-\dfrac18\right)\tan A=\dfrac38\tan3A$$

and I should leave it here.

Comment: Who said anything of a multiple? I mean, why should it be a multiple of tan24°?

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: @You-know-me, Observe the  angles $8,24,72,216:$   Each is three times of the previous

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it...

Comment: @You-know-me, Put $A=8^\circ,24^\circ,72^\circ,216^\circ$ one by one